# Arrows with direction and proportional to attribute

Tags: qgis, symbology, line

my data looks like this:

```
> main
   end.station start.staion Freq end.latitude end.longitude        end.station
1          359          519  929     40.75510     -73.97499 E 47 St &\nPark Av
2          477          465 5032     40.75641     -73.99003   W 41 St &\n8 Ave
3          484          519 1246     40.75500     -73.98014   W 44 St &\n5 Ave
4          484          318 2654     40.75500     -73.98014   W 44 St &\n5 Ave
5          492          267 1828     40.75020     -73.99093   W 33 St &\n7 Ave
6          492          498  957     40.75020     -73.99093   W 33 St &\n7 Ave
7          492          362 1405     40.75020     -73.99093   W 33 St &\n7 Ave
8          493          477 1582     40.75680     -73.98291   W 45 St &\n6 Ave
9          493          529  728     40.75680     -73.98291   W 45 St &\n6 Ave
10         529         2021 1748     40.75757     -73.99099   W 42 St &\n8 Ave
   start.latittude start.longitude              start.station
1         40.75188       -73.97770         Pershing\nSquare N
2         40.75514       -73.98658        Broadway &\nW 41 St
3         40.75188       -73.97770         Pershing\nSquare N
4         40.75320       -73.97799 E 43 St &\nVanderbilt\nAve
5         40.75098       -73.98765        Broadway &\nW 36 St
6         40.74855       -73.98808        Broadway &\nW 32 St
7         40.75173       -73.98754        Broadway &\nW 37 St
8         40.75641       -73.99003           W 41 St &\n8 Ave
9         40.75757       -73.99099           W 42 St &\n8 Ave
10        40.75929       -73.98860           W 45 St &\n8 Ave
```

I've managed to connect the `end.station` and `start.station` points in QGIS using the MMQGIS Hub lines tool.   However, I am unable transform these lines into arrows that a) point in the direction of the path, and b) have a width that is proportional to FREQ.

I have tried with the Arrows plugin, but to no avail.  All I get are very long lines that extend infinitely.  How does one solve this? [image]

[image]

Comment: is there really no way to use arrows with proportional widths in QGIS?